# Inserting default values in tables using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails automatically inserts values for columns like created_at and updated_at. Can i configure rails in such a way that it updates more columns. For example all my tables have a column called user holding the currentuser value, can I default rails ti insert user for any database change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the before_save function in your model, unless I've misunderstood the question.

```
before_save :defaults

def defaults
   #some stuff to set your defaults
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use a before_filter in the model, e.g.

```
before_update :set_value

def set_value
   self.value = "hello"
end
```

Comment: On further reading, it seems that you want to associate all resources with the current_user.  Why don't you scope all resources under the current_user and then you shouldn't need to use a filter like the above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveRecord callbacks to trigger logic when changing states, such as before saving an object to the database. The created_at and updated_at columns in automatically updated when either an object is created (before_create), or updated (before_save). You can define your own callbacks using the class methods defined in the ActiveRecord::Callbacks namespace. An example would be

```
# app/models/example.rb
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :do_something

  def do_something
    self.value = value
  end
end
```

If you are specifically wanting to record the user that created, updated, or deleted a record, you can save some work and use the Userstamps Rails plugin to automatically record the user. This plugin is located at https://github.com/delynn/userstamp

```
# app/models/example.rb
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  model_stamper
end

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Userstamp
end
```

You will need to add the userstamps columns onto each of your models on which you want to record user actions.

More information on ActiveRecord callbacks can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Information on timestamps can be found here:
ActiveRecord timestamps: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html